# How to deal with discrete variables in Multivariable Time Series forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, embeddings

I am tackling this time series forecasting problem to basically predict number of sales in the future

training dataset looks like this:

```
id   date         store   item    sales
 0. 2018-01-01.     1.      1       13
 1  2018-01-02      1       1       12
 2  2018-01-03      1       1       16
 3  2018-01-04      1       1       18
```

Use this to predict sales on these days:

```
id     date     store    item
 0   2018-01-01   1       1
 1   2018-01-02   1       1
 2   2018-01-03   1       1
 3   2018-01-04   1       1
```

I am not sure how to incorporate store and item variables into the model. Some idea I came up so far is:

1. Use embedding to represent categorical variables to continuous vectors
2. Feed it into NN model to learn relationships between these variables and sales
3. create univariate time series with sales and add lags, feed through LSTM to learn
4. somehow combine these two for prediction

Any thoughts would be super appreciated.